# Can I "fill" a chicken pot pie 24 hours before cooking it?

Tags: baking, pie, pastry, crust

I have made chicken pot pie filling. I was hoping to lay the pie pastry in the pie pan, fill it with the filling, lay the second pie pastry on top, and then refrigerate the raw pir in the fridge for a day. I want to do this so I can just pop it in the oven the next day without any work. This would work great preparing for parties and such.

My concern is that resting the filling on the pie crust for a day would affect the pie crust somehow. Perhaps the liquid would seep into the pastry and affect texture or cooking for example.

Can I "fill" a chicken pot pie 24 hours before cooking it?

Comment: On the preparing for parties -- you might want to try individual ramekins, with just a top crust.   (fill in advance, but let them warm up some before putting the top crust on top).  You can also go the slightly 'deconstructed' route of ramekin with a biscuit cooked separately and set on top.  I've also made [chicken pot pie bombs](https://tastykitchen.com/recipes/main-courses/chicken-pot-pie-bombs/) in advance (although I used goat cheese instead of the cream cheese & replaced the cream of chicken soup) and they held up rather well made ahead & reheated for a picnic

Comment: @Joe good thinking!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely not. As the other poster said but I will say with no "I think", I will say I know it will ruin the pastry.  You will end up with a gummy crust that will never give you the flaky texture that pie doughs are famous for. It would probably also leave you with a somewhat dry filling as much of the liquid would then be in the crust.

Comment: You might get by if you slather the lower crust with a heavy coat of butter, but I wouldn't trust it, and I wouldn't chance it for anything but a home meal (eat what you have, or eat nothing) before I'd made that work several times. The *do* make frozen pot pies somehow, and the bottom is not mucilaginous.

Answer (score 4):

I think the moisture would destroy the pastry. You could always roll out the pastry and prepare the filling in advance and store them separately in the fridge. Then you just put it together and pop in the oven. That shouldn't take many extra minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the filling ahead of time, stash in the fridge, and hat way you just have to lay the pie pastry and fill it.

Comment: You might want to warm the filling back up before filling, so you don't throw off the cooking time by having something too cold sitting against the pastry.